# avoid time out error in selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, automation, timeout, selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE and i have to generate a script, in which if time out error occurs it will redirect me to gmail and in that i will send email to customer support. If time error doesn't come then next steps will execute.

Is it possible to generate such script?
can we set timer in selenium IDE?

Or is there any solution to avoid time out error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about selenium IDE but a general solution in such cases is (using Python syntax):

```
try:
    # code that may generate timeout error
except TimeoutError:
    # redirect to gmail
else:
    # code that should be executed if there is no timeout error
```

Comment: Yes, you are right..but i am looking for selenium IDE to do same.